# MoviePy error: the file /tmp/testvideo.mp4 could not be found ! Please check that you entered the correct path

Tags: python, django, moviepy

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail from an uploaded video using Moviepy. Here's my function (`instance` is the uploaded `FileField` (video)):

```
def generate_thumbnail(instance):
    filename = instance.image.path.split('/')[-1]
    print(filename) #successfully prints name of uploaded file: "testvideo.mp4"
    thumbnail = VideoFileClip('/tmp/%s' % filename) #this line sparks the error
    name = random_string() + '.png'
    time = random.randrange(60)
    thumbnail.save_frame('media/' + name, t=time, withmask=True)
    instance.thumbnail = name
```

`thumbnail = VideoFileClip('/tmp/%s' % filename)` returns the error:

```
OSError at /post/
MoviePy error: the file /tmp/testvideo.mp4 could not be found !
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

Full Traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/site/post/views.py" in post
  50.                     generate_thumbnail(instance)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/site/functions/helper_functions.py" in generate_thumbnail
  45.     thumbnail = VideoFileClip('/tmp/%s' % filename)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py" in __init__
  81.                                          fps_source=fps_source)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py" in __init__
  32.                                    fps_source)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py" in ffmpeg_parse_infos
  272.                       "path.")%filename)

Exception Type: OSError at /post/
Exception Value: MoviePy error: the file /tmp/testvideo.mp4 could not be found !
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Is your video actually located at /tmp/testvideo.mp4? You seem to be passing a path, then splitting off part of it and make a new path. I'd assume (but can't confirm from information provided) that the original path is where the file is actually located

Comment: I'm not sure where the `tmp` directory is located? Also, what do you mean by the 'original path'?

Comment: In line 2 you do a path split, so you had some path like /home/user/movie.mp4. Then you take movie.mp4 off of that and and put it on a different location on your system /tmp/movie.mp4 -- then it looks at the new location and didn't find the file. Try just removing `.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: When I remove `.split('/')[-1]` I get `MoviePy error: the file /tmp//Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/site/media/testvideo.mp4 could not be found !`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your test in the comments, there is confirmation of what path is being passed into the function. If you run it this way, you'll get the original path to the file which should at least solve the file not found error.

```
def generate_thumbnail(instance):
    filename = instance.image.path
    thumbnail = VideoFileClip(filename)
    name = random_string() + '.png'
    time = random.randrange(60)
    thumbnail.save_frame('media/' + name, t=time, withmask=True)
    instance.thumbnail = name
```

Comment: Thanks everything works now. Just an extra question, do you know how I could send that thumbnail to my javascript client side? Or is that not possible?

Comment: I don't anything about your setup, but so long as you save the file somewhere that your server can access it should be able to provide it to a client. Give it a try and post a question if you get stuck